# Django Error: Reverse for 'delete_ingredient' not found. 'delete_ingredient' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'd appreciate whatever help you can give to get me past this block.  Thanks!

The code breaks when I modify the code that used to work to add Delete functionality.  When I run the code without the modified *urls.py* I get the error.

## **The error is:**

```
> NoReverseMatch at /ingredients/
Reverse for 'delete_ingredient' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ingredients/
Django Version: 4.1.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'delete_ingredient' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Dropbox\Python Projects\Django Projects\djangodelights\djangodelights_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  inventory.views.IngredientsView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Dropbox\Python Projects\Django Projects\djangodelights\djangodelights_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Python Projects\\Django '
 'Projects\\bwa-django-final-project-main\\bwa-django-final-project',
 'C:\\Users\\Python Projects\\Django '
 'Projects\\djangodelights\\djangodelights_env\\Scripts\\python39.zip',
 'd:\\users\\miniconda3\\DLLs',
 'd:\\users\\miniconda3\\lib',
 'd:\\users\\miniconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\Python Projects\\Django '
 'Projects\\djangodelights\\djangodelights_env',
 'C:\\Users\\Python Projects\\Django '
 'Projects\\djangodelights\\djangodelights_env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 19 Oct 2022 19:44:34 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Dropbox\Python Projects\Django Projects\bwa-django-final-project-main\bwa-django-final-project\inventory\templates\inventory\ingredients_list.html, error at line 30
Reverse for 'delete_ingredient' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
20          </thead>
21          <tbody>
22          {% for ingredient in object_list %}
23              <tr>
24                  <td>
25                      <a href="{% url "update_ingredient" ingredient.id %}">{{ ingredient.name }}</a>
26                  </td>
27                  <td>{{ ingredient.quantity }}</td>
28                  <td>{{ ingredient.unit }}</td>
29                  <td class="price">${{ ingredient.price_per_unit|stringformat:".2f" }}</td>
30                  <td><a href="{% url "delete_ingredient" ingredient.id %}"
31                         style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">❌</a></td>
32              </tr>
33          {% endfor %}
34          </tbody>
35      </table>
36       <a href="{% url "create_ingredient" %}" style="display:
37       inherit; text-align: center; border-radius: 15px; text-decoration: none;
38       color: inherit; padding: 4px; background-color: lightgreen;">➕</a>
39  {% endblock %}
```

---

## **Original Code**

*ingredients_list.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% block title %}Django Delights{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <a href="{% url 'add_ingredient' %} ">Add New Ingredient to Inventory</a>
    <hr/>
    <table class="inventory-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for ingredient in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{% url "update_ingredient" ingredient.id %}">{{ ingredient.name }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.unit }}</td>
                <td class="price">${{ ingredient.price_per_unit|stringformat:".2f" }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("logout/", views.log_out, name="logout"),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('ingredients/', views.IngredientsView.as_view(), name="ingredients"),
    path('ingredients/new', views.NewIngredientView.as_view(), name="add_ingredient"),
    path('ingredients/<slug:pk>/update', views.UpdateIngredientView.as_view(), name="update_ingredient"),
    path('menu/', views.MenuView.as_view(), name="menu"),
    path('menu/new', views.NewMenuItemView.as_view(), name="add_menu_item"),
    path('reciperequirement/new', views.NewRecipeRequirementView.as_view(), name="add_recipe_requirement"),
    path('purchases/', views.PurchasesView.as_view(), name="purchases"),
    path('purchases/new', views.NewPurchaseView.as_view(), name="add_purchase"),
    path('reports', views.ReportView.as_view(), name="reports")
]
```

---

## **Modified Code**

*ingredients_list.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% block title %}Django Delights{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <!-- <a href="{% url 'add_ingredient' %} ">Add New Ingredient to
    Inventory</a> -->
    <hr/>
    <table class="inventory-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for ingredient in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{% url "update_ingredient" ingredient.id %}">{{ ingredient.name }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.unit }}</td>
                <td class="price">${{ ingredient.price_per_unit|stringformat:".2f" }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url "delete_ingredient" ingredient.id %}"
                       style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">❌</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
     <a href="{% url "add_ingredient" %}" style="display:
     inherit; text-align: center; border-radius: 15px; text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit; padding: 4px; background-color: lightgreen;">➕</a>
{% endblock %}
```

*urls.py*

from django.urls import path

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("logout/", views.log_out, name="logout"),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('ingredients/', views.IngredientsView.as_view(), name="ingredients"),
    path('ingredients/new', views.NewIngredientView.as_view(), name="add_ingredient"),
    path('ingredients/<slug:pk>/update', views.UpdateIngredientView.as_view(), name="update_ingredient"),
    path('ingredients/<id>/delete', views.DeleteIngredientView.as_view(),
         name="delete_ingredient"),
    path('menu/', views.MenuView.as_view(), name="menu"),
    path('menu/new', views.NewMenuItemView.as_view(), name="add_menu_item"),
    path('reciperequirement/new', views.NewRecipeRequirementView.as_view(), name="add_recipe_requirement"),
    path('purchases/', views.PurchasesView.as_view(), name="purchases"),
    path('purchases/new', views.NewPurchaseView.as_view(), name="add_purchase"),
    path('reports', views.ReportView.as_view(), name="reports")
]
```

---

When I run it with the modified *urls.py,* I get:

**Hmmm… can't reach this page**

**127.0.0.1** refused to connect.

**Try:**

- Search the web for 127 0 0 1
- Checking the connection
- Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Your `urls.py` does not have any item with `name="delete_ingredient"`.

Comment: Also as a side note, `<a href="{% url "update_ingredient" ingredient.id %}">` The inner quotes should be single-quotes, not double-quotes.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your suggestion.

As I included at the end of my post when I modify _urls.py_ to include a reference with _name="delete_ingredient",_ I can no longer reach 127.0.0.1:8000.


When I use single quotes, I get the same error with the following line changed:  
 _30                 <td><a href="{% url 'delete_ingredient' ingredient.id %}"_

Comment: Ahh, I overlooked the modified version of urls.py.  If you're getting connection refused with this code, that means the application is having some error and wasn't able to start up.  Look in the error log.

Comment: Does `views.py` contain a view named `DeleteIngredientView`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Initially, it did, but when I rolled back the project to its current status, it did not.  I added it back, and things are working.  Thanks.